# Enterprise magneto 2 setup using composer update

Tags: magento, magento2

Trying to execute: composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-tested)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an install-able set of packages.

Problem 1
    - The requested package magento/magento-cloud-metapackage could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability for more details.
 - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it

Read https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md for further common problems.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Create auth.json file in Magento root directory

add repo.magento.com username Password

```json
{
    "http-basic": {
        "repo.magento.com": {
            "username": "<user key>",
            "password": "<password Key>"
        }
    }  
}
```

Run command "Composer update"

---

You can get the username/password for your account by checking the access keys from within the [Magento Marketplace](https://marketplace.magento.com/customer/accessKeys/) (via [Documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Magento repo added in composer.json file.

```
    "repositories": {
    "composer-magento": {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
    },
```

Which version you are tyring to install? 
Also, check that you have in your composer.json file.

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
```

Comment: It is not working dear. I have same code in my composer.json file.

Comment: Problem 1- The requested package magento/product-enterprise-edition could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details. - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it
Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to install Magento Commerce (former Enterprise)

```
 composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-enterprise-edition <install-directory-name>
```

Comment: The requested package magento/product-enterprise-edition could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Comment: in that case, do first this: 
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-enterprise-edition <install-directory-name>

Comment: It is not working..[InvalidArgumentException]                           
  Package magento/magento-cloud-metapackage not found  
                                                       

show [--all] [-i|--installed] [-p|--platform] [-a|--available] [-s|--self] [-N|--name-only] [-P|--path] [-t|--tree] [-l|--latest] [-o|--outdated] [--ignore IGNORE] [-m|--minor-only] [-D|--direct] [--strict] [-f|--format FORMAT] [--] [<package>] [<version>]

Answer (score 0):

Run `composer show magento/magento-cloud-metapackage --all`

And in result you will be able to check which versions are available for this package.

Comment: [InvalidArgumentException]                           
  Package magento/magento-cloud-metapackage not found  
                                                       

show [--all] [-i|--installed] [-p|--platform] [-a|--available] [-s|--self] [-N|--name-only] [-P|--path] [-t|--tree] [-l|--latest] [-o|--outdated] [--ignore IGNORE] [-m|--minor-only] [-D|--direct] [--strict] [-f|--format FORMAT] [--] [<package>] [<version>]

Comment: IT is still not working. Throwing below error:                                                                                           [InvalidArgumentException] 
  Package magento/magento-cloud-metapackage not found  
                                                       

show [--all] [-i|--installed] [-p|--platform] [-a|--available] [-s|--self] [-N|--name-only] [-P|--path] [-t|--tree] [-l|--latest] [-o|--outdated] [--ignore IGNORE] [-m|--minor-only] [-D|--direct] [--strict] [-f|--format FORMAT] [--] [<package>] [<version>]

Comment: Are you sure you have correct repository credentials for Magento Enterprise edition?

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed this error two times and it got resolved the next day. I believe there is either some upgradation done by the magento due to which the package is not available to download from the repo.

My suggestion is to either contact the magento support team / try it out the next should probable work.

I had tried it on next day and it starting updating.